# Is the convention for error bars to present one or two standard errors?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-error

I am plotting error bars in ggplot2 with `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar`. `geom_errorbar` asks for `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics. If I want the error bars to be std errors, is the convention to have `ymax = mean_value + standard_error` and `ymin = mean_value - standard_error`, or is it `ymax = mean_value + (1/2)*standard_error` and similarly for `ymin`?

My question is essentially: **Is the length of the bar equal to 2*stderr or to stderr?**

Comment: I would first ask myself if you really want to plot a barplot and error bars together...

Comment: I have never seen people use $\pm 0.5 SE$, and would say $\pm 1 SE$ is more conventional from papers I've read. Whatever you choose, label it so that the reader knows how you calculated the errorbars!

Comment: I've seen that in some fields, +- 2 sigma error bars are common, while in other disciplines +- 1 sigma error bars are common.  You'd do well to find out the convention in your field of research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me the best default approach is to always use confidence intervals, using methods that recognize that the intervals should usually be asymmetric.  Use of $\pm k\times$SE implies symmetry that doesn't hold when the underlying data distribution is very asymmetric.

If you want to show data distributions rather than precision of estimates of central tendency, then plotting the 0.25 and 0.75 quantiles along with the median often work well.